# Munkres, Analysis on Manifolds, Problem 38-5

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis

I am having trouble doing this problem. I know that we need to use Stokes' Theorem. $D_3$ is easy. The problem is I can't seem to picture a shape whose boundary is $D_1$ and $C_1$ and/or $D_1$ and $C_2$ (the way the lines are drawn seems to make a connected smooth surface impossible). Similarly, creating a smooth surface that has $D_2$ and $C_1$ and/or $D_2$ and $C_2$ as boundaries also seems impossible.

**Question:**
Let S be the subset of $\mathbb{R^3}$ consisting of the union of:

i) the z-axis

ii) the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1, z=0$

iii) the points $(0, y, 0)$ with $y \geq 1$

Let $A$ be the open set $\mathbb{R}^3-S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $C_1, C_2, D_1, D_2, D_3$ be the oriented 1-manifolds in $A$ that are pictured in Figure 38.3. Suppose that $F$ is a vector field in $A$, with $curl F = 0$ in $A$ that $\int_{C_1} \langle F,T \rangle ds = 3$ and $\int_{C_2} \langle F,T \rangle ds = 7$.

What can you say about the integral $\int_{D_i} \langle F,T \rangle ds$ for $i=1,2,3$? Justify your answers.

[image: Analysis on Manifolds]

Comment: Hint for $D_1$: imagine decomposing the loop as $a_1+a_2+a_3-a_2$ where $a_1$ and $a_3$ trace out subsets of $D_1$ and $a_2$ is a new curve (a kind of “diameter” of $D_1$), and so $b_1:=a_1+a_2$ and $b_2:=a_3-a_2$ are both closed curves. Then the line integral over $D_1$ is the sum of the line integrals over the closed curves $b_1$ and $b_2$, which can be very nicely related to the line integrals over $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I am a bit puzzled with the construction of $b_2$. If I understand correctly, $\alpha_2$ is not a subset of $\alpha_3$ but for two points, so is $b_2$ equal to $\alpha_3$ minus two points? If all this is true, my question is the following: If we have a closed 1-manifold (ie $c_1$) and an open 1-manifold without boundary (ie $b_2$), can we construct a connected 2-manifold whose boundary is the union of these two 1-manifolds? If so, it *feels* a bit dangerous to do so. Is there something I am missing that clearly allows this construction? Many thanks